# Why does urlunparse return extra slash after manipulating scheme?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to add a scheme to urls which don't have it. I want to use the following code:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse

url = 'example.com'
parsed = urlparse(url)
parsed = parsed._replace(scheme='https')
new_url = urlunparse(parsed)
print(new_url)
```

Instead of this:

```
https://example.com
```

the script is returning this:

```
https:///example.com
```

which throws and error if I try to get the url like so:

```
requests.get('https:///example.com')
```

Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

I am using:

```
Windows 10
Python 3.6.1
Anaconda 4.4.0
```

Comment: Three slashes is due to your urls is considered as path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial string is parsed as a path component because there is no scheme to indicate that the string is a host:

```
urlparse('example.com')
# ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='example.com', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Perhaps add a scheme to make this explicit:

```
urlparse('http://example.com')
# ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='example.com', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Comment: This is duplicate question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7289533/8353711).